# Target class [blade.compiler] does not exist in laravel 8

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-8

After composer installation, When I run php artisan serve command then this errors are shown-
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException

Target class [blade.compiler] does not exist
in my laravel 8 project

Error in that file, vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:879

Code :

```
try {
    877▕             $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
    878▕         } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
  ➜ 879▕             throw new BindingResolutionException("Target class [$concrete] does not exist.", 0, $e);
    880▕         }
```

Comment: What version were you using before?

Comment: Please share more details. How is this problem related to Composer itself? What have you tried to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

this problem can occur if you have old version of php, so try to upgrade your php version to php >= 8  following this :

-1 download php from the official website :
from this link : https://www.php.net/downloads

or for windows this link : https://windows.php.net/download#php-8.1

-2 extract the zip and put the folder in your php folder

-3 update your system environment variables

Comment: Thanks Man for your valuable solution